# Using SSO, does this count as only one authentication factor?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, sso

When using Google SSO, does this count as only one factor of authentication or as many factors as I use for my google account?

If it counts as a single factor, would this be "something I have" in the sense that I have access to this account?

Comment: What do you mean by _as many as I use for my google account_  ?

Comment: @elsadek I mean the amount of factors I have for the authentication on google itself

Comment: that's single sign on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSO is not an authentication factor, so, there are no factors. SSO tells the site to grab an authentication token from the IDP (Google). So, you aren't authenticating.